# Accessing non-static varibles from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, static, components

Quick question:

I am writing in unity c#, and have an *array* containing several instances of the same object. I want to change a *non-static* `bool` in every member of the array, and set it to `true`. How would I do this?

I have played around with *for-loops*, and searched both here and at the unity forums, but cannot find an answer. I don't believe my messy, faulty code would be of any help. Anybody care to enlighten me? :)

**EDIT:** Thanks for the tips, will try them now. The code was asked for, excuse the mess:

```
Component[] toMerge;

for (int t = 0; t < mergeTargets.Length; i++) {
    toMerge[t] = mergeTargets[t].gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    toMerge.readyToMerge = true;
}

for (int t = 0; t < toMerge.Length; t++) {
    toMerge[t].readyToMerge = true;
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you post any code you have tried before, as it's hard to understand what you want. What object do you have, what field you want to change?

Comment: Are you looking for a *loop*? `foreach`?

Comment: considering that you want to change every object in the array, why doesnt `for(int i = 0; i < array.length();i++) { object.elem = true; }` work? ( I'm not used to C# so you would have to adapt your syntax

Comment: Also if you want to change value of some objects, you better use `List<T>`, and in `foreach` change it like `obj.Field = newValue;`

Comment: `foreach (var item in array) item.MyField = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *allocate* `mergeTargets.Length` items in `toMerge` array and address not the array but its item:

```
    //DONE: We need mergeTargets.Length items in toMerge
    Component[] toMerge = new Component[mergeTargets.Length]; 

    for (int t = 0; t < mergeTargets.Length; i++) {
      toMerge[t] = mergeTargets[t].gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();
      //DONE: [t] - we want to change item, not the array
      toMerge[t].readyToMerge = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I spent so long trying to figure that out!